# Proximity sensor not working properly after first use

Tags: ios, swift, proximity

I am building a game with SpriteKit that requires use of the proximity sensor. I have a swipe gesture that turns proximity sensing on, when the proximity sensor senses something it turns off. My problem is that the first time I swipe and put my hand over the sensor, the functions runs and everything works fine. The second time I swipe and put my hand over the sensor the screen just turns black, when I move my hand away from the proximity sensor it then runs the function and everything works. I want it to activate and run the function when I put my hand over the sensor instead of when I remove my hand. Does anybody no how I could fix this?

Proximity sensor code:

```
func setProximitySensorEnabled(_ enabled: Bool) {
    let device = UIDevice.current
    device.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = enabled
    if device.isProximityMonitoringEnabled == true {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(proximityChanged), name: .UIDeviceProximityStateDidChange, object: device)
        print("added observer!!!")
    } else {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIDeviceProximityStateDidChange, object: nil)
        print("removed observer!!!")
    }
}

func proximityChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let device = notification.object as? UIDevice {
        print("\(device) detected!")
        print("An object is near!!")

        vibrate()

        setProximitySensorEnabled(false)

    }
}
```

Swipe function:

```
func swipe() {
    print("swipe detected")
    setProximitySensorEnabled(true)
}
```

Comment: setProximitySensorEnabled(false) remove from func proximityChanged.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that somewhere in my project set UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = false after I add the observer. The selector method would not get any notification then.